# Оптимизация алгоритма на Питоне для 1994 задаче на тимусе

Tags: python-3.6

Ребят, делаю задачу 1994 на Тимусе. На С++ аналогичный алгоритм проходит, а на питоне работает долго (из-за этого не проходит проверку). Как можно оптимизировать данный код?

```
maxn = 200
maxk = 20

def C(n, m):
    k = n - m
    if (m > k):
        m = k
    if (m==0):
        return 1
    akk = n - m + 1
    k = n - m + 2
    for i in range (2, m+1):
        akk = akk / i * k + akk % i * k / i
    return akk

def Result(N,K,A):        
    for n in range(1,N+1):
        for k in range(1,K+1):
            maximum = 0.0
            for d in range(1,n+1):
                res = 0.0
                maxi = max(0,d-k)
                mini = min(d, n-k)
                for i in range (maxi,mini+1):
                    res += (float)(C(n-k,i)*C(k,d-i)*A[n-k-i][k-(d-i)])
                res /= (float)(C(n,d))
                maximum = max(maximum,res)
            A[n][k]= maximum
    return A             

A = [0.0]*(maxn+1)
for j in range (maxn+1):
    A[j]=[0.0]*(maxk+1)

x1,x2 = input().split(' ')
N = int(x1)
K = int(x2)
N = N-K

for i in range (1,maxn+1):
    A[i][0] = i

A = Result(N,K,A)       


print (A[max(0,N)][K])
```

ЗАДАЧА:
1994. План императора
Ограничение времени: 1.0 секунды
Ограничение памяти: 64 МБ

Галактическая Республика просуществовала более двадцати пяти тысяч лет, после чего была преобразована в первую Галактическую Империю. Утвердив свою власть и положение, верховный канцлер Палпатин издал Декларацию Нового порядка и провозгласил себя Императором Галактики.
Высшим органом Республики был Галактический Сенат. Даже после возвышения Империи многие сенаторы имели большой вес в обществе. Сенат мешал императору Палпатину в достижении его целей и был преградой на пути к могуществу. Император понимал, что для полного захвата власти ему необходимо действовать изнутри, поэтому он завербовал некоторых членов Сената. Днём новоявленные шпионы ничем не отличались от обычных сенаторов и лишь ночью служили Империи. Вечером каждый шпион получал задание на устранение одного из сенаторов, верных Старому порядку. Приказ незамедлительно исполнялся и ближайшей ночью все заявленные сенаторы погибали. Палпатин хотел избавиться от проблемы как можно быстрее, поэтому раздавал задания так, чтобы каждый раз погибало максимально возможное количество сенаторов.
Столкнувшись со смертями, сенаторы заподозрили, что среди них есть шпионы императора. Тогда было принято решение каждый день сокращать состав Сената до тех пор, пока смерти не прекратятся или пока в составе не останутся только шпионы. После исключения сенатор теряет уважение общественности и больше не является помехой для Палпатина. С другой стороны, если он был шпионом императора, то и продолжить убивать по ночам он не сможет.
Сенаторы предполагают, что ночью каждый шпион убивает ровно одного сенатора, верного Старому порядку. Шпионы ничем себя не выдают, поэтому Сенат каждый день выбирает только количество исключаемых, личности же выбираются случайным образом. Сенат действует оптимально и выбирает количество исключаемых так, чтобы максимизировать математическое ожидание числа действующих к окончанию противостояния сенаторов, верных Старому порядку.
Сейчас из n членов Сената целых k являются шпионами, и император только что выдал им новые задания. Помогите Палпатину посчитать математическое ожидание числа сенаторов, верных Старому порядку, которые останутся в составе Сената к концу противостояния.
Исходные данные
В единственной строке входных данных находятся два числа n и k (1 ≤ k ≤ n ≤ 200, k ≤ 20).
Результат
Выведите одно число — ответ на задачу с абсолютной или относительной погрешностью не более 10−6.
ПРИМЕР (4 1) - вход, 0,666666666 - выход

Comment: вот сейчас все понеслись узнавать, что это за тимус, и искать задачу.... Приведите условие здесь (отредактировав вопрос)

Comment: Я бы как минимум здесь скобки расставил, сомневаюсь, что этот кусок без них работает как задумано: `akk = akk / i * k + akk % i * k / i`

Comment: Я бы сюда вообще декоратор numba.jit припахал и всё бы летало, но там наверняка так нельзя )